# R - creating list from variable of names

Tags: r, list

Consider the following code

```
names = c("1","2","3")
values = c(1.0,1.5,0.5)
list(names = values)
```

This produces the following list

```
$names
[1] 1.0 1.5 0.5
```

But the list I desire is:

```
$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 1.5

$`3`
[1] 0.5
```

In other words, `list("1"=1.0,"2"=1.5,"3"=0.5)`

So, how can I create such a list by starting with variables `names` and `values` as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setNames` and `as.list`:

```
setNames(as.list(values), names)
# $`1`
# [1] 1
#
# $`2`
# [1] 1.5
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Map(function(x,y) y,names,values)

$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 1.5

$`3`
[1] 0.5
```

Comment: You actually only need `Map(function(x,y) y, names, values)`